# How do you generate UML Use Case diagram in VP UML 10 from code

Tags: uml

How do you generate a reverse engineered UML Use Case Diagram in Visual Paradigm UML version10 from code? 
I have been able to generate Sequence diagrams using the instant reverse function. I want to generate the use case diags the same way. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Case diagrams give a purely conceptual, very high-level view of your system. Since they are at such a completely different level of abstraction than code, an automatic reverse engineering of use cases isn't sensibly possible.